# Powershell remoting session timeouts and dealing with dead hosts

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script that will connect to a list of servers, some of the servers would have issues such as being offline, winRM issues, general server health etc. I would like to attempt connection to the host, and have a timeout for winrm connectivity issues.

So far I have come up with the script below.

```
$list = @('server1','server2','server3')

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $list -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -credential Get-Credential
$timeout = 30
$remote = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()} -AsJob 
$remote | Wait-Job  -Timeout $timeout
$output = $remote | Receive-Job 

foreach ($server in $output)
{
    invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "servername" -Query "insert into mytable select '$server'"
}
```

**What is the problem.**

In the example above, I have no way of tracking servers that failed and what ends up happening is that I can see my list has server1, server2 and server3, if after checking my database I only find server1 and server2, I have to do a diff to work out that server3 must have timed out or failed.

**What am i trying to achieve.**

To have a  script that can deal with thousands of servers, run a simple command on each host  and return back the result, for servers that timeout or experience issues, log the particular server, log a progress log from the array list and as a bonus, if the script can run in parallel to speed up the progress of the execution.

Comment: How is this question different from your previous ? As I see it, this is a duplicate.

Comment: Different solution, now I am using sessions with a timeout and jobs. If i edited the previous question, it would cause confusion. Please tell me if i am wrong here and I will happily edit the previous question.